# Laravel one to many relationship insert array

Tags: php, laravel

I get from my form page an array of values in the form of:

```
"managed_cluster" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Benelux"
    1 => "Germany & Austria"
]
```

I have 2 models:
User

```
public function clusters()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cluster');
}
```

So I have the table users with id and name column and I have the table clusters with id, user_id and cluster_name column. The link between the 2 tables is the users.id and clusters.user_id

I know that if I use `App\User::find(1)->clusters()->saveMany(x)` then x needs to be a set of objects but I was wondering how I could do that straight with the array? Or do I need to do a foreach on the array and then save the clusters one by one (from what I got from the form)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the function **createMany()** which accepts an array as an attribute, for example:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$user->clusters()->createMany([
    [
        'cluster_name' => 'cluster1',
    ],
    [
        'cluster_name' => 'cluster2',
    ],
]);
```

More info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Comment: how can I use a foreach in this case because this array can be variable

Comment: you can use the foreach in this way:

$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach($managed_cluster as $name) {
$cluster = new App\Cluster(['cluster_name' => $name]);
$user->clusters()->save($cluster);
}